# How to not cache if certain condition is met on Rails 6.1 +Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make it so if its directReports it shouldn't get it from rails cache. I tried to just return it but that doesnt seem to work.

```
 ''' # dont get it from cache if DirectReports
  when PerformanceManagement::V0::EmployeeFilter::DirectReports
    return 
  else
    filtered_results = loaded_records
  end'''
```

plz don't be mean it's my first time posting.

Answer (score 0):

For such things you can create a method that just acts as a wrapper to handle the cache-or-not condition:

```
def main_logic_here
  ... expensive calculation
end

def main_logic_wrapper
  if true
    main_logic_here
  else
    Rails.cache.fetch(...) { main_logic_here }
  end
end
```